# setcookie PHP doesn't work in a right way

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie

I have such situation: I do `setcookie("bla",md5("bla"),time()+36000)`.
After this I do see this cookie in the browser but If I will write `print_r($_COOKIE)` on the server - there will be not exist cookie with key "bla". Any ideas?

here is the listing:

```
  setcookie("login_cookie",md5($result['user_password']."solt"),time()+36000);
  setcookie("login_info",$result['user_id'],time()+36000);
  header("Location:{$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']}");
  exit();
```

Comment: *Right after* you set the cookie, or on the next request?

Comment: I THINK what @deceze is getting at is, - if you set the cookie, it won't be available to print until the NEXT page load - not the current one.

Comment: `setcookie` _does_ work in the right way!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the following (set the path argument to the root):

```
setcookie("login_cookie",md5($result['user_password']."solt"),time()+36000, '/');
setcookie("login_info",$result['user_id'],time()+36000, '/');
```

I have a feeling you're going out to a different directory in the redirect which is why it's not displayed, of course, I may be wrong.

Comment: No problem, as an aside you should also be careful about subdomains (including www.), you may need to set the cookie domain (next argument) to be `.domain.ext`, rather than the default, absolute domain. This will carry the cookie across everywhere!

Answer (score 2):

`$_COOKIE` is one of the super globals which contain information passed in the HTTP request. You will only see it when a request has been made by a browser which already has the cookie, *not* directly after having called `setcookie()`.

Also, in your code example, you appear to be trying to concat using the `+` operator:

```
$result['user_password']+"solt"
```

PHP uses the `.` operator for concat.

Comment: thnx - but I know that. And tried it even after a few reloads. But browser shows it and $_COOKIE doesn't. Why?

Comment: about "+" - sorry it is like a typo. Ofcourse should to use "."